# Unable to create AWR report

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When I try to generate an AWR Report in Oracle, I keep getting this error:

```
[Error] Execution (37: 21): ORA-00904: 
"SYS"."DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY"."AWR_REPORT_HTML": invalid identifier
```

The command I run in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(SYS.DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.AWR_REPORT_HTML(550758650, 1, 3385, 3386));
```

I also tried with the GUI in Oracle Developer (View -> DBA) from the menu, I got the same error.  Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are you connected as SYS or SYSTEM?

Comment: No, I logged on using the schema user.  This account was provided by the Oracle DBA.  I am thinking this account must not have the proper privileges.  I know this account is definitely not a "dba" but it can do lots of stuff.  Maybe this isn't one of them.   What are the exact permissions needed to run AWR?  But the error message does not point to permission.  Or does it?

Comment: A regular user does not have the necessary privileges to retrieve an AWR report. You need at least `execute` privilege on the `dbms_workload` package and probably `select` privileges on the needed ASH tables. The `select_catalog_role` role might be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Let me explore the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you do not have the rights to create an AWR report. Try to create it through the root user

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Do as follow.

conn / as sysdba

SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql

Specify the Report Type

```
AWR reports can be generated in the following formats. Please enter the
name of the format at the prompt. Default value is 'html'.

'html' HTML format (default)
'text' Text format
'active-html' Includes Performance Hub active report

Enter value for report_type:
old 1: select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('&&report_type','html')) report_type from dual
new 1: select 'Type Specified: ',lower(nvl('','html')) report_type from dual

Type Specified: html

old 1: select '&&report_type' report_type_def from dual
new 1: select 'html' report_type_def from dual



old 1: select '&&view_loc' view_loc_def from dual
new 1: select 'AWR_PDB' view_loc_def from dual



Current Instance
```